# unit ball of $(C([0, 1], \mathbb{R}), \mathrm{d}\infty)$ is not compact

Tags: continuity

I am trying to show that the unit ball of $(C([0, 1], \mathbb{R}), \mathrm{d}\infty)$ is not compact.
thanks

Comment: For your first question, consider the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=x^n$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

The constant functions $f_t(x)=t$ for all $x$ give an uncountable compact subset of $C[0,1]$.

The sequence $\{1,x,x^{2},...\}$ has no convergent subsequence , so the unit ball is not compact.